# How to extend parent class from nested class, if nested class is applied?

Tags: sass

I have this component that renders:

```
{
  isTopLevel ? (
    <div className="top-level">
      {hasChildren ? (
        <div className="expand-icon">
          <Icon />
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

Is there a way, using scss, to add another property to `.top-level` ***if*** `.expand-icon` is applied?

So far I have this:

```scss
.top-level {
    margin: 0 $spacing-8 0 0;
    width: $spacing-16;
    height: $spacing-16;

    .expand-icon {
        cursor: pointer;

        @extend .header-column;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

I wish to apply red color to `.top-level` if `.expand-icon` is applied.

Comment: What you are looking for is a parent selector and it doesn't exist in css. You could easily add a new class regarding `hasChildren` value though.

Comment: I'm using scss.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are using `scss`. `scss` will compile into `css`